What is the purpose of bs (block size) parameter for dd command?
I have used the dd command a few times. I used it to create a bootable USB from the ubuntu.some.release.iso file. I know there is a bs (block size) parameter, but I don't understand its exact meaning. How does this parameter impact the copy process? I have chosen different values, but it seems that it does not matter a lot. Can anyone explain this to me?

that linked article didn't explicitly mention that bs translates to the size parameter in read() and write() system calls. It may matter for pipes and odd devices (tape drives), but not really for regular files. I edited it a bit

see also: dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?
